# Eager load polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :receiver, foreign_key: :receiver_id, polymorphic: true
```

.

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
```

.

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
```

.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :provider, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :owners, dependent: :destroy
```

So in a Conversation, `sender` can be an Owner or a Provider. With this in mind, I can make queries like:

```
Conversation.includes(sender: :account).limit 5
```

This works as intended. The problem is when I want to use a where clause in associated model Account. I want to filter conversations which associated account's country is 'US'. Something like this:

```
Conversation.includes(sender: :account).where('accounts.country' => 'US').limit 5
```

But this wont work, I get the error `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :sender`

What is the correct way of doing this kind of query?

I've also tried to use `joins`, but I get the same error.

Comment: tried `Conversation.preload...`?

Comment: Yes, gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found myself a solution, in case anyone else is interested. I ended up using `joins` with a SQL query:

```
Conversation.joins("LEFT JOIN owners ON owners.id = conversations.sender_id AND conversations.sender_type = 'Owner'
                  LEFT JOIN providers ON providers.id = conversations.sender_id AND conversations.sender_type = 'Provider'
                  LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = owners.account_id OR accounts.id = providers.account_id").
                where('accounts.country' => 'US').limit 5
```